# angular http get url number parameter modified

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

This should be very simple but I don't know why i can't get it right . i am building ionic app for a wordpress blog , where i want to get a single post id and display a single post , i can conform that the id is passed but when i enter in a http.get call , for some reasons it gets modified to

```
http://myURL/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/%7Bid%7D
```

This is my code

```
// Load a single post
    loadSinglePost(id:number): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://bongosoka.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${id}')
      .map(res => <Post[]>res.json());
    }
```

How do I get it to return the actual id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks for string interpolation

```
return this.http.get(`http://bongosoka.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${id}`)
```

See also https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html